# Django MySQL Apache setup on Ubuntu 64b EC2 instance; No response

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Following the tutorial here http://ericwconner.com/?p=347

Of course changed

```
ServerName www.mysite.com
```

in mysite.wsgi script to

```
ServerName xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Removed the ServerAlias as well

When I put in my Public DNS all I get is a "204 No Content"

Any advice/requests for more info more than welcome.

I don't get it, tutorial seems straightforward enough...

Comment: Hi what have you got in the wsgi, apache config and apache log?

Comment: Those things don't go in your wsgi script, but in the Apache configuration file.

Comment: Is this the etc/apache2/httpd.conf file? I tried that, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As @Burhan has mentioned in the comments, it should go inside the Apache configuration file. Have a look at [official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/) on how to do this. If you are using virtualenv(as you probably should) look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv) too.